# Generate Event based on class name

Tags: angular, events

I have a custom component which I created in Angular which looks like this:

[image]

When I click on one of the indicators, the green portion animates and lands on said indicator:

[image]

I have a new requirement of being able to set the value that was originally clicked on at the time of rendering. So for example, you configure this at some point, on some page, and if you revisit that same page at a later time, the component would automatically reflect your previous selection.

For example, an input possibly named `[indicatorSelected]="'60'"` that would generate the second image.

Here is the code that controls the animation:

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event']) public onClickIndicator(event: Event) {
    const targetNode: HTMLDivElement = event.target as HTMLDivElement;
    const classList: DOMTokenList = targetNode.classList;
    if (classList.contains('indicator')) {
        const centerX: number = targetNode.offsetLeft + targetNode.offsetWidth;
        const centerXOffset: number = 10;
        this.innerShell.nativeElement.style.width = `${centerX + centerXOffset}px`;
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<div class="shell">
  <div *ngFor="let interval of intervals; let first = first; let last = last; let i = index;"
    class="indicator"
    (click)="onClickTime(i)"
    [ngClass]="{'first': first, 'last': last}">
    <p class="seconds">{{ interval * (i + 1) }}</p>
  </div>
  <div #innerShell class="inner-shell"></div>
</div>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to leverage this existing functionality in order to generate a click event that I can then pass to this method.

If I obtain the class name of the indicator that I want to click, can I simulate a click based on that?

Comment: Can you include the custom component HTML markup in the question? Or, even better, provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, I just added it. Thanks.